# How can I jump from one placeholder to the next in Xcode autocompletion?

Tags: xcode

When Xcode autocompletes an method for me, it gives me blue blocks for parameters. I always go into the first, but then I click into all next ones rather than fast going there by keyboard commands. I guess that there are some good ones to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default is Command-/, but you can customize that in the key bindings section of XCode's settings window.

Comment: Using the Tab key is better option, as mentioned below.

Comment: And use Shift-Tab to go backwards.

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 3.2 (Snow Leopard), you can also use the Tab key to navigate between parameters. Personally, I find this more intuitive than Command-/.